# Custom control in Lazarus / Freepascal DBGrid (or StringGrid)

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, dbgrid, stringgrid

I have asked this question on the Freepascal site and no one seems to be able to help.

I only want to display the text from a specified column in a DBGrid / StriingGrid in a control (for example a TLabel) displayed on the grid. The control must must be displayed on all rows, not just the selected row.

All I want to do is display the row / cell text as a hyperlink, so when the mouse is over the text it changes to crHandPoint, and when I click the text (not the cell) it opens the hyperlink in the associated program.

Comment: Then you need many labels, and probably hook OnDrawColumnCell event of the grid. Or, if your grid is well fixed, may be you can drop on the form as many labels you need, without resorting to dynamic creation of controls, but the first solution is better.

Comment: there will be a max of 20 rows on screen. or im open to other suggestions

Comment: Perhaps `TLinkLabel`s will do. Have you tried?